# jqueryui datepicker show extra week when conbine numberOfMonths+showOtherMonths

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm having an issue with the jqueryui datepicker, I have an inline datepicker on a div with numberOfMonths=3, showOtherMonths=true, and when a month have 6 weeks the month next to it have 6 week too even if it shouldn't, this extra week belong to the next month, here is an image of what i'm talking about:
[extraweek image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zODkD.jpg)

This is my datepicker code:

```js
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  showCurrentAtPos: 1,
  firstDay: 1,
  showWeek: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  defaultDate: '20/05/2016',
});
```

```css
#datepicker{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

I would like to know if someone had already dealed with this because I didn't find any info on this issue, i've tried to delete the extra tr week once the datepicker is loaded but I prefer to seek a better solution.

Thanks a lot for any response.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @SachinAnand sorry to say I haven't found a solution to this issue yet -.-